# Filling a matrix using a dataframe in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, dataframe

I have an empty matrix `m`:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames = list(c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4"),
                            c("x", "y")))
```

And need to fill the matrix using the data frame d

```
d <- data.frame(site = c("x", "y", "u", "v"), 
                species = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1"), 
                freq = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1))
```

so that if `rowname(m)` is equal to `d[, "species"]` and `m[, "x"]` is equal to the `d[, "site"]` then `d[, "freq"]` in entered in the correct place in matrix m i.e. returning:

```
m <- matrix(c(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, 
            dimnames = list(c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4"),
                            c("x", "y")))
```

I have tried:

```
m[d[, c("species", "x")]] <- d[, "freq"]
```

I suspect I am not doing the data frame indexing properly? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably not the best way to do it but this is working:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){m[rownames(m)==d[i,2],colnames(m)==d[i,1]] <- d[i,3]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Do you foresee any stability issues with it however?

Comment: I honestly can't think of any.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of cast and merge works fine.

Setting up the data

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames = list(c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4"),
                            c("x", "y")))
d <- data.frame(site = c("x", "y", "u", "v"), 
              species = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1"), 
              freq = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1))
```

Doing the calculations

```
library(reshape)
dc <- cast(species ~ site, data = d, value = "freq")
md <- as.data.frame(m)
md$species <- rownames(md)
md <- merge(
    md, 
    dc[, c("species", "x")], 
    all.x = TRUE, 
    by = "species", 
    suffixes = c("", ".tmp"))
md$x[!is.na(md$x.tmp)] <- md$x.tmp[!is.na(md$x.tmp)]
md$x.tmp <- NULL
```

You could symplify the code when you convert d$site to a factor containing rownames(m)

```
d <- data.frame(
    site = c("x", "y", "u", "v"), 
    species = factor(
        c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1"), 
        levels = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4")), 
    freq = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1))
cast(species ~ site, data = d, value = "freq", add.missing = TRUE)
```

You get the frequencies of y, u and v as a bonus. If you don't want them, remove them from d a priori

```
cast(species ~ site, data = d, value = "freq", add.missing = TRUE, 
    subset = site == "x")
```

Use the fill argument is you want to convert NA to another value

```
cast(species ~ site, data = d, value = "freq", add.missing = TRUE, 
    subset = site == "x", fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the answer from plannapus because it is shorter. Is your version more stable though?

Comment: I have add to code simplified code. It all depends on whether m is already defined or whether you can create m from d.