# Convert a dataframe to an object of class "dist" without actually calculating distances in R

Tags: r, distance

I have a dataframe with distances

```
df<-data.frame(site.x=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"),   
site.y=c("B","C","D","C","D","D"),Distance=c(67,57,64,60,67,60))
```

I need to convert this to an object of class "dist" but I do not need to calculate a distance so therefore I cannon use the dist() function. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem not to long ago and solved it like this:

```
n <- max(table(df$site.x)) + 1  # +1,  so we have diagonal of 
res <- lapply(with(df, split(Distance, df$site.x)), function(x) c(rep(NA, n - length(x)), x))
res <- do.call("rbind", res)
res <- rbind(res, rep(NA, n))
res <- as.dist(t(res))
```

Comment: This is very nice solution thanks! Just one question. Why is the last row label dropped and is there anyway this can be avoided? Thanks again

Comment: One issue with this otherwise nice approach is that you have to create the full distance matrix to create the `"dist"` object. That is a little wasteful and `rbind()`ing large data sets may be slow. As you already have the vector of distances, and `"dist"` class objects are just a vector with attributes, it is easier and more efficient to directly add attributes to the vector of distances. See my Answer below for an example and details.

Answer (score 16):

There is nothing stopping you from creating the dist object yourself. It is just a vector of distances with attributes that set up the labels, size, etc.

Using your `df`, this is how

```
dij2 <- with(df, Distance)
nams <- with(df, unique(c(as.character(site.x), as.character(site.y))))
attributes(dij2) <- with(df, list(Size = length(nams),
                                  Labels = nams,
                                  Diag = FALSE,
                                  Upper = FALSE,
                                  method = "user"))
class(dij2) <- "dist"
```

Or you can do this via `structure()` directly:

```
dij3 <- with(df, structure(Distance,
                           Size = length(nams),
                           Labels = nams,
                           Diag = FALSE,
                           Upper = FALSE,
                           method = "user",
                           class = "dist"))
```

These give:

```
> df
  site.x site.y Distance
1      A      B       67
2      A      C       57
3      A      D       64
4      B      C       60
5      B      D       67
6      C      D       60
> dij2
   A  B  C
B 67      
C 57 60   
D 64 67 60
> dij3
   A  B  C
B 67      
C 57 60   
D 64 67 60
```

**Note**: The above do no checking that the data are in the right order. Make sure you have the data in `df` in the correct order as you do in the example; i.e. sort by `site.x` then `site.y` before you run the code I show.

Comment: This solution may be too neat: It assumes that Distances are in the correct order (column major ordering of the lower triangle without diagonal). In general, such an ordering cannot be expected in user data.

Answer (score 2):

`?as.dist()` should help you, though it expects a matrix as input.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. I have already calculated the distance using my own function. However, creating dendrograms or doing a PCA etc. requires a distance object.

Comment: you have to convert your data.frame to a matrix using the solution you got in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116049/filling-a-matrix-using-a-dataframe-in-r) and then use `as.dist` (you only need the lower triangle of the matrix)

Comment: Please read the help page carefully to understand what an object of class dist actually is.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming in from google... The acast function in the reshape2 library is way easier for this kind of stuff.

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, site.x ~ site.y, value.var='Distance', fun.aggregate = sum, margins=FALSE)
```