# CSV of Distances to Dist Object R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a dataframe to an object of class “dist” without actually calculating distances in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343637/convert-a-dataframe-to-an-object-of-class-dist-without-actually-calculating-di)

I have a very large csv file (so a for loop takes too long in R) of similarities between keywords that when I read into a data.frame looks like:

```
> df   
kwd1 kwd2 similarity  
a  b  1  
b  a  1  
c  a  2  
a  c  2
```

I would like to convert this to a dist object, like this:

```
> dObject  
  a b  
b 1    
c 2 0
```

I was unable to get this to work:
[Convert a dataframe to an object of class "dist" without actually calculating distances in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343637/convert-a-dataframe-to-an-object-of-class-dist-without-actually-calculating-di)

Another idea I had was to create a sparse matrix using Matrix(), but I am unsure how to populate the matrix efficiently because my csv is fairly large - maybe an apply function?

Maybe reshape()?

---- Update ----
This seems to work on the toy dataset above:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/efficient-way-to-populate-matrix-in-r

However, in this example, they use a matrix(), but I would like to use Matrix() that is sparse for memory reasons.

--- Furthermore ----
There is a similar posting from before. However, I don't think that the advice from it works for this case in which their isn't a link between every element in the dataset - the csv doesn't contain the pairwise similarities between all keywords as in the previous post:
[Convert a dataframe to an object of class "dist" without actually calculating distances in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343637/convert-a-dataframe-to-an-object-of-class-dist-without-actually-calculating-di/12289896#12289896)

Comment: What have you tried that it doesn't work? I think we should wait with the closing as duplicate until the OP has time to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Generate some dummy data (since you didn't provide your data)
df <- data.frame(V1=sample(letters, 10, TRUE),
                 V2=sample(letters, 10, TRUE),
                 V3=sample(200, 10, TRUE))
```

`df$V1` and `df$V2` are now factors, possibly with different levels, so we need to make them comparable, e.g. make sure `"a"` in `V1` is the same as `"a"` in `V2`.

```
# Convert letters to integers
my.objects <- sort(unique(c(as.character(df$V1), as.character(df$V2))))
df$V1 <- match(df$V1, my.objects)
df$V2 <- match(df$V2, my.objects)
```

Create an empty distance matrix and populate it with the values in `V3` at the locations specified by `V1` and `V2`. Finally we convert it to a proper `dist` object.

```
# Create an empty distance matrix
n <- length(my.objects)
dist.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
i <- as.matrix(df[-3])
dist.mat[i] <- dist.mat[i[,2:1]] <- df$V3

my.dist <- as.dist(dist.mat)
```

Comment: Hi, my data is similar to the example I wrote above. The letters are supposed to be keyword names and the third column is their similarity. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: This line didn't work for me:
dist.mat[i] <- dist.mat[i[,2:1]] <- df$V3

Comment: This is what I'm using:
kwds = unique(c(array(df[,1]), array(df[,2])))

df = as.matrix(df)
colnames(df) = c(1,2,3)

f = function(x){
            x = which(x == kwds)
}
if(nrow(df) <= 40000){
    m = matrix(0, ncol = length(kwds), nrow = length(kwds), dimnames = c(list(kwds), list(kwds)))
    m[df[,c(1,2)]] = df[,3]
}else{
    i = array(sapply(df[,1], f))
    print('Making second list...')
    j = array(sapply(df[,2], f))
    print('Filling matrix...')
    m = sparseMatrix(i,j, x = as.numeric(df[,3]), dimnames = c(list(kwds), list(kwds)))
}
class(m) <- 'numeric'
d = as.dist(m)
distances = 1 - d

Comment: Whether you have letters or keywords doesn't matter, it should work for any data type. If the last line didn't work, make sure `i` is a matrix with two columns. If that's not it I'll find it hard to diagnose.