# Filling one data frame of permutations using another in r

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame which is all possible permuations of a,b, and c in 'both directions'

```
df1<-data.frame("x"=c("a","a","b"),"y"=c("b","c","c"),"A"=1:3 ,"B"=4:6,"C"=0,"T"=10:12)
df2<-data.frame("x"=df1$y,"y"=df1$x, "A"=df1$A,"B"=df1$B,"C"=df1$C,"T"=df1$T)
df<-rbind(df1,df2)
  x y A B C  T
1 a b 1 4 0 10
2 a c 2 5 0 11
3 b c 3 6 0 12
4 b a 1 4 0 10
5 c a 2 5 0 11
6 c b 3 6 0 12
```

which I want to use to fill a second empty data frame

```
empty<-data.frame("x"=c("a","c"),"y"=c("b","a"),"A"=0,"T"=0)

  x y A T
1 a b 0 0
2 c a 0 0
```

thereby producing:

```
filled<-data.frame("x"=c("a","c"),"y"=c("b","a"),"A"=1:2,"T"=10:11)

  x y A  T
1 a b 1 10
2 c a 2 11
```

I have tried a for loop without luck

```
for(i in 1:nrow(empty)
{
    if("x" == df$x && "y" == df$y)
    {
        empty[i,"A"]<-df$A 
        empty[i,"T"]<-df$T
    }
}
```

and also the answer from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116049/filling-a-matrix-using-a-dataframe-in-r) about filling a matrix without any success. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to do this? Can't you just subset your original `df`?

Comment: I don't think I can subset do to a permutation issue

Comment: What exactly are you "permuting"? What's wrong with a solution like this `df[1:2, c(1, 2, 3, 6)]` (basic subset by row and column numbers) or this `df[df$x=="a" | df$x=="b", names(df) %in% c("x", "y", "A", "T")]`, or better yet, this `df[df$x %in% c("a", "b"), names(df) %in% c("x", "y", "A", "T")]` (subsetting with matched values for rows and columns)?

Comment: I adjusted the question to reflect what I mean by permutations...I tried your suggestions but couldn't get it to work...Any other suggestions now that the question is perhaps a bit more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge`:

```
merge(df[c("x","y","A","T")], empty[c("x","y")])
#   x y A  T
# 1 a b 1 10
# 2 c a 2 11
```

And as @mrdwab points out, you don't need to create an `empty` dataframe that will hold the final data. Instead, let `merge` do that for you. All you need is a data.frame that has the combinations of `(x,y)` pairs you want to extract:

```
extract.keys <- data.frame(x = c("a","c"), y = c("b","a"))
merge(df[c("x","y","A","T")], extract.keys)
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for the real data. I ave adjusted the question to more accurately reflect the real data frame. Thanks for your answer sorry for perhaps not explaining what I really wanted to do the first time around....

Comment: @Elizabeth, please update the question again. As it currently stands, flodel's answer still works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Moving my comments to an "answer", I'm not sure what the end goal of this is. To me, even with the concept of permutations added in, this seems like a question of subsetting. That is to say, if prior knowledge already exists on how to create the "`empty`" `data.frame`, we could simply skip the step of creating that object and having to merge, and directly subset.

Given that `a` and `b` will give six permutations as variables `x` and `y`, and knowing that we are only interested in combinations `a+b` and `c+a`, we can easily use `paste0()` on columns `x` and `y` with which to test.

Using `df` from the updated question:

```
df[paste0(df$x, df$y) %in% c("ab", "ca"), 
   names(df) %in% c("x", "y", "A", "T")]
#   x y A  T
# 1 a b 1 10
# 5 c a 2 11
```

Of course, @flodel's answer works just fine, but I'm just confused why one would need to go to the trouble of creating an empty `data.frame` to fill in when subsetting by column and row indexes suffices.

### Update

Because I have other work I should be doing, I decided to do some benchmarks. Here are the results:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(subsetting = df[paste0(df$x, df$y) %in% c("ab", "ca"), 
                 names(df) %in% c("x", "y", "A", "T")],
          merge.keys = merge(df[c("x","y","A","T")], 
                    data.frame(x = c("a","c"), 
                               y = c("b","a"))),
          merge.empty = merge(df[c("x","y","A","T")], empty),
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
                      "relative", "user.self"))
#          test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3 merge.empty          100   0.321 6.294118     0.324
# 2  merge.keys          100   0.387 7.588235     0.384
# 1  subsetting          100   0.051 1.000000     0.048
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful and I learned something new....benchmarks! Thanks again.